# CSS box-shadow causing elements to move in Safari

Tags: css

If I have HTML and CSS like this:

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
}

a:hover {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then, using macOS Safari (v15.4), hovering over items, they move around to make space for the top of the box-shadow. In the left-hand column it even changes how many items appear in each column.

In iOS Safari (iOS 15.6) only the item at the top of the second column moves.

Firefox and Chrome keep all the elements still.

Any suggestions how to get Safari to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't check in the new version of Safari right now, but in older versions of IOS Safari (>=10.3) sometimes a similar solution helped:

```css
ul * {
  will-change: opacity;
}

ul {
  columns: 2;
}

a:hover {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's magic! I'd never heard of `will-change` before. Reading about it, I will be very targeted with it.

Comment: @PhilGyford, `will-change: opacity` is used here only as a trick to get around rendering bugs when using CSS `columns` in IOS Safari. But this forces a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for each element, which is not very good for performance if there are many, so you can add this property only for Safari using [hacks with css selectors supported only in Safari](https://browserstrangeness.github.io/css_hacks.html#safari). This problem is very old and surprisingly it is still not fixed in new versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. A shame we still need to use browser-specific hacks - I hoped we'd left those behind with old Internet Explorers or Netscape 4!

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
try using grid will help solve the problem
(you might need to change the order of your list to fit your style)

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but that does change the display order of the list items. And I don't want to change the actual order of them because then they'll be in the wrong order for anyone using screen readers etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use grid:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
   grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
   grid-auto-flow: column;  
}

a {
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 5px transparent;
}


a:hover {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='col'>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's semantically a single list and so I'd really like to keep it as such.

Comment: Answer updated to use grid